# Где можно хранить dll файлы?

Tags: c#

Доброй ночи - подскажите возможно ли такое реализовать и если можно в какую сторону копать....
В папке с игрой лежит dll файл,а котором прописана авторизация - если авторизация прошла,то на данный пк качается dll уже со всеми функциями игры, но эта dll НЕ ДОЛЖНА быть видна пользователю, НО Я СМОГ ЕЙ ПОЛЬЗОВАТСЯ!!!

Comment: Хранить dll в зашифрованном виде

Comment: Никак. На своей машине юзер царь и бог, у него есть администраторские права, и он видит всё, что видит ваша программа.

Comment: @Nikita в каком именно?

Comment: Вы можете немного затруднить юзеру работу, если, например, получите DLL в память, и [загрузите прямо из памяти](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7(v=vs.110).aspx). Но вы не запретите ему получить вашу DLL синффером, и вытащить ключ расшифровки из исходника, пройдя его под отладчиком.

Comment: @VladD в сети есть модикация для игры,которую я имею ввиду - там dll  качается с сайта создателя - и ее нету на пк,но сервер может ее использовать - RustExtended.dll это авторизация - RustExtended.Core.dll со всеми функциями

Comment: @Сергей: Сервер? О каком именно сервере вы говорите?

Comment: @VladD игровой сервер - там закидываешь dll в папку с игрой - далее запускаешь exe - если в dll пройдена авторизация то качается dll,но не на пк,так как ее нет не где,но она в какой то кодировке что-ли качается.Игра может ей пользоваться - кстати функции вызываются через Invoke

Comment: @Сергей: Ну как я уже говорил, DLL можно загрузить, на сохраняя на диск. Судя по всему, это серверная программа и делает.

Comment: @VladD а как загрузить в память?можешь дать ссылку на пример или туториал?

Comment: @Сергей: Ну, если грузить данные из интернета, их же не обязательно сохранять на диск? Можно оставить в памяти.

Comment: Похоже вам нужно смотреть в сторону  Assembly.Load(byte[])

Comment: авторизация на сервере должна быть и всё.

Comment: Использование Assembly.Load усложнит получение этой DLL, но уж точно не сделает невозможным. Всегда можно среверсить запрос, сгенерировать такой же, получить байтовый массив и сохранить его в DLL. Ну или из памяти процесса на крайний случай можно вытащить. Ответ простой - [безопасность через неясность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) - это очень плохой подход. Авторизация должна быть безопасной, даже при полностью открытом исходном коде.